# Hibernate: CascadeType.ALL not saving all entities because of PERSIST on OneToOne relation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Using the properties below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
public class B extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable, Comparable<B>, Cloneable {
  ...
  @JsonBackReference
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name ="a_id")
  @Cascade( value = { CascadeType.ALL } )
  private A an;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
public class A implements Serializable{
  @Id
  @Column(name="a_id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
  private B b;
}
```

it saves only the first entity, after that it returns this error for the other ones:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: A; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: A
```

I'm not familiar with PERSIST. I don't know if using only CascadeType.MERGE or CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE would solve the problem, I mean they worked, but I'd rather know how to fix the persistance.

Comment: As a side note: it should be `mappedBy = "an"`, not `mappedBy = "a"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you try to save or entities ? By calling "SaveOrUpdate" method or "Persist" ?

Comment: By the Persist.

Comment: It seems that "Persist" is used for saving entity the first time. SaveOrUpdate can be called once the entity is already created. I think you should try to call "SaveOrUpdate" method instead of.

Comment: Isn't CascadeType.ALL supposed to do both? Anyway, what if I use @PrePersist inside the class and, if so, how?

Comment: I'm not talking about "CascadeType". I'm talking about which Hibernate method you are calling to save your datas in database. No matter which cascade type you set. I guess your problem may be you don't call the right hibernate method to save your datas.